# Title and singer of that english-sounding song in Tokyo Ghoul Root of Aogiri anime?

Tags: tokyo-ghoul

I loved the sound of the song that sounds like English (I can't understand the words but I know most of it are not *nihongo*) that is usually being played on dramatic scenes in Tokyo Ghoul RA. Can someone tell me its title and its singer?

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga SE.It would be much better if you provide link(mainly youtube) of clip of the song you are referring to

Comment: As an alternative, it would also be great if you could pinpoint the episode and the timing when the track starts playing.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry I forgot to post some links. I'll do just that next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I usually do in cases like this is look the show up on AnimeNewsNetwork, where it lists all the insert songs used in the show:

http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=16318

I don't have enough reputation to post more links yet, but it looks like it might be the songs "On My Own" or "Glassy Sky" (both on Youtube). They're both song by Katherine Liner, BTW.